# Nested Layouts in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I want to create a nested layout in next.js. I have also a parent layout that contains `Header` and `Footer` components. I am using that Layout in the `_app.js` file.

**_app.js file**

```
import Layout from "../components/Layouts/Layout";
import "../styles/globals.css";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

**Sidebar.js**

```
import Link from "next/link"
export default function Sidebar() {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><Link href="docs/page1"><a>Page 1</a></Link></li>
                <li><Link href="docs/page2"><a>Page 2</a></Link></li>
                <li><Link href="docs/page3"><a>Page 3</a></Link></li>
                <li><Link href="docs/page4"><a>Page 4</a></Link></li>
                <li><Link href="docs/page5"><a>Page 5</a></Link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Now I have a **docs** page with a `Sidebar` component. Now I do not want to render the `Sidebar` component on every docs page. I want to create a nested layout that only renders in a particular route. In my case, the nested `layout` should be rendered in the `/docs` path. Now I have pages inside the `pages/docs` directory something like this =>
[image]

Now I want a nested layout that would be wrapped up of the parent `Layout`. The nested layout may contain a `Sidebar` component.

Comment: see this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69-mnojSa0M